# merge forked repo with testing branch of original repo

Tags: git, github, merge, bitbucket

How can we merge forked repo with original repo devops branch

below is given the original repo branches

```
Original repo
   master branch
   development branch
   devops branch
   testing branch
```

And this is the forked repo branch. it has 3 branch

```
forked repo
   master branch
   development branch
   modify branch
```

I want to merge master branch of fork repo in testing branch of original repo. After this merge again I want to merge testing branch with master branch of original repo.

Comment: You can merge any branch with any other branch.  It doesn't matter if it was forked.  Forking isn't really a `git` concept.  It's more of a `github` concept. And `github` doesn't impose any limits in that area.  Regardless of the `github` terminology, it's all the same repo when you fork a project.  Forking doesn't really create a new repo.

Comment: @JoelFan Is that true? A GitHub fork is not really a repo? It's not a true clone? I find that a little difficult to believe. Can you prove it?

Comment: A fork is no more or less a "clone" than when you "clone" a repo onto your local hard disk.  Both the fork and the original repo have exactly the same graph of commits, with the same commit id's.  You can easily merge a branch from your "fork" back into the original project.  They are the same repo.  That is most of the point of github.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to merge master branch of fork repo in testing branch of original repo

Don't want that. Reserve the `master` branch for merging things *into* it. You should not be merging `master` into something else except as part of coordinating two long-lived branches, e.g. `master` and `development`.

Instead, make a new branch, e.g. `contributeToTesting`. Put a commit on it so that it has an independent existence if necessary. Now, using the GitHub web interface, submit a pull request to the upstream (the original) asking to merge your `contributeToTesting` into their `testing`. When they approve the pull request, that is the merge.

> After this merge again I want to merge testing branch with master branch of original repo.

So you want to merge `testing` into `master`, both of them back at the upstream (original) repo? You can only do that if you *own* the upstream repo. To do so, open the upstream repo in the GitHub web interface and submit a pull request to merge `testing` into `master`.

Note that my answers have assumed you want to do pull requests. If you don't, then you can do all this on your own local clone. Clone the fork to your local, and give it *two* remotes: `origin` (the fork at GitHub) and `upstream` (the original repo at GitHub). Now, if you own both GitHub repos, you are free to merge anything into anything, pull anything, push anything, whatever. Just specify clearly, when you give a command, which remote's branch you are talking about.